# How do I parse a single record or an array of records in a json field using JsonPath

Tags: json, jq, jsonpath

I have a json value that can contain a single record or an array, I need to extract the ID field of these records and gather them in an array. The resulting element should be an array with 1 or more ID values.

Input 1  Single record

```
{
  "CVE": {
    "ID": "CVE-2022-26138","URL": "foo.bar" }
}
```

Input 2  An array of two records

```
{
  "CVE": [
     { "ID": "CVE-2019-2969","URL": "foo.com" },
     { "ID": "CVE-2019-3030","URL": "bar.com" }
  ]
}
```

I tried the JSONPath expression `$.CVE.ID` which results in `["CVE-2022-26138"]` for Input 1 but returns empty array on the Input 2.

Then I tried the JSONPath expression `$.CVE.*.ID` which results in empty array [] for Input 1 but gives me correct output for Input 2 `["CVE-2019-2969", "CVE-2019-3030"]`

My question is, is there a single JSONPath expression I can use that gives me non-empty result in either input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a recursive descent `..`:

```
$.CVE..ID
```

Note, however, that if your objects contain nested `ID` properties, this will pick up those as well.

Try it out at https://json-everything.net/json-path

Comment: Worked beautifully, neat trick. Didn't know about  recursive descent

Answer (score 1):

By using the filters `objects` and `arrays`, you can handle different types differently, like here using `.[]` only on arrays. Then, using `-n` and `inputs` lets you access multiple input objects at once, thus collect their values into a single final array.

```bash
jq -n '[inputs.CVE | objects, arrays[] | .ID]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Hj6gkztXGE3)